# Passing async function to tokio::spawn from another thread

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

**Challenge:**

Main thread is sync and there's additional thread which runs Tokio Runtime.

I need to pass an async function from the sync thread to tokio thread.

**Code:**

```
use std::{future::Future, thread, thread::JoinHandle};
use tokio::{
    sync::mpsc::{unbounded_channel, UnboundedReceiver, UnboundedSender}
};

type Job = Box<dyn (FnOnce() -> dyn Future<Output = bool>) + Send>;


pub fn thread_init(receiver: UnboundedReceiver<Job>) {
    let handler = thread::spawn(move || {
            thread_main(receiver);
    });
}

pub fn main() {
   let (sender, receiver) = unbounded_channel::<Job>();
   thread_init(receiver);
}

#[tokio::main(worker_threads = 1)]
async fn thread_main(mut receive: UnboundedReceiver<Job>) {
    loop {
        match receive.try_recv() {
            Err(e) => match e {
                tokio::sync::mpsc::error::TryRecvError::Disconnected => {}
                tokio::sync::mpsc::error::TryRecvError::Empty => {
                    yield_now().await;
                }
            },
            Ok(job) => {
                tokio::spawn(job());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get these errors:

```
`dyn FnOnce() -> (dyn std::future::Future<Output = bool> + 'static) + std::marker::Send` is not a future
the trait `std::future::Future` is not implemented for `dyn FnOnce() -> (dyn std::future::Future<Output = bool> + 'static) + std::marker::Send`
dyn FnOnce() -> (dyn std::future::Future<Output = bool> + 'static) + std::marker::Send must be a future or must implement `IntoFuture` to be awaited
required for `Box<dyn FnOnce() -> (dyn std::future::Future<Output = bool> + 'static) + std::marker::Send>` to implement `std::future::Future`
```

```
`dyn FnOnce() -> (dyn std::future::Future<Output = bool> + 'static) + std::marker::Send` cannot be unpinned
consider using `Box::pin`
required for `Box<dyn FnOnce() -> (dyn std::future::Future<Output = bool> + 'static) + std::marker::Send>` to implement `std::future::Future`
```

*Note: this is not the actual use case, but a simplification of it.*

**Question**: how can I correctly pass an async function to tokio?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you may want to look at using Handle.spawn (https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Handle.html#method.spawn) which you can construct using Handle.current (https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Handle.html#method.current). This lets you spawn a future to the tokio runtime directly from a thread other than a tokio thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tokio::spawn()` takes a future, not a function.  You need to call this function and give the returned future to `tokio::spawn()`:

```
tokio::spawn(job());
// Add parens   ^^
```

Once you do this, you'll receive three errors, each of which shows up after solving the last one:

- You can't invoke a function that returns an unsized type (`dyn Future` in this case).  Box the return type to solve this.
- The future given to `tokio::spawn()` must be `Unpin`.  Wrap the box in a `Pin` to solve this.
- The future given to `tokio::spawn()` must also be `Send`.  Add the `Send` constraint to `dyn Future`.

Fixing these three issues, the `Job` type becomes:

```
type Job = Box<dyn (FnOnce() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = bool> + Send>>) + Send>;
```

This is a bit of a mouthful.  Because the general type `Pin<Box<dyn Future + Send>>` comes up so frequently, the `futures` crate provides a handy generic type alias [`BoxFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/type.BoxFuture.html) to make expressing these types less verbose.  Using this type alias, we can simplify the definition of `Job` to:

```
type Job = Box<dyn (FnOnce() -> BoxFuture<'static, bool>) + Send>;
```

---

Having said all of this, there isn't really a convincing reason I see to have `Job` be a boxed function.  Why can't it just be the boxed future?  You don't really gain much by adding the `FnOnce` layer.  You can just do:

```
type Job = BoxFuture<'static, bool>;
```

If you do this, you don't need to add the parens -- `tokio:spawn(job)` will work just fine since `job` is already a future.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer!
I think I do want to execute the function in the tokio thread, so I will need to run `tokio::spawn(job())`. I'm not sure what the correct signature/definition of the function should be...

Comment: @Omeriko Keep in mind that futures don't run until polled, so it's usually not necessary to delay creation of the future until you want to begin polling it. That's why I suggest `Job` simply be a future type. Until you give it to `tokio::spawn()`, it will not do anything.

Comment: I did a test (printing the ThreadId inside a job) and saw that there's a new thread for each running thread, instead of being executed by the tokio thread.

Comment: @Omeriko I'd need to see the code you're testing to determine what's going on. Without the code I could only make guesses about it.

Comment: Here: https://gist.github.com/omerbn/c43272abb748bf7dfe6dad0a93a5009f

Comment: @Omeriko I don't even know how you got this to compile. You don't import `yield_now`, your module `tokio` conflicts with the `tokio` crate, the `tokio::Job` type is private so it can't be used from the main module... there's a lot of problems here.

Comment: @Omeriko The `Job` type doesn't even have the correct function return type... it's missing the `Pin<Box<_>>` layers. Can you please upload the _working_ code that you tried?

Comment: U are correct. sorry. Now it's compiling: https://gist.github.com/omerbn/c43272abb748bf7dfe6dad0a93a5009f

Comment: @Omeriko I think you just want `#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]` instead of `#[tokio::main(worker_threads = 1)]`. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=90c8c4792a326eaebba14a5c7f65ea79)

Comment: That's super awesome!! thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a question - is there a way to pass a ref to that async function? (motivation: there's a thread-local data I'd like these functions to use)

Comment: @Omeriko Futures passed to `tokio::spawn()` must be `'static` so I'm pretty sure the answer is "no."